# Keep Single dashes and single space in string - Negative Lookahead

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a java regex pattern that exclude any text that have two or more consecutive dashes or two or more consecutive spaces.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "text"? words? lines?

Comment: words, i m using a regex validator in struts 2 application. i need to make sure that a user first name and last name does not have two consecutive spaces or dashes.

Comment: Provide your sample input, expected output.

Comment: jean-claude will be a valid user first name and jean--claude will be invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you will use your regex in mechanism similar to `matches` method you may be looking for something like

```
^(?!.*(--|  )).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
s = s.replaceAll("( )+|(-)+", "$1$2");
```